# Flutter Build error is resulting to a error , Could not load compiled classes for build

Tags: flutter

The whole code was working well last week, and now I try to open the same project and run the flutter build apk

It shows below error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':location'.

> Could not load compiled classes for build file 'D:\\flutter.pub-cache\\hosted\\pub.dartlang.org\\location-4.4.0\\android\\build.gradle' from cache.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for the project ':location' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for the project ':location' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
  ore log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 16s
  Gradle task assembly release failed with exit code 1
```

Running flutter doctor...

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)

[√] Chrome - develop for the web

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.3.6)

[√] Android Studio (version 2021.3)

[√] Connected device (3 available)

[√] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!

I tried cleaning the pub cache folder and also running pub get commands, but the build is not succeeding

Comment: Whenever something like this happens, I try `flutter clean`, then `flutter pub get` and `dart pub get`, and then build the apk. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: @bingalooo , yeah I tried it already. But no luck

Comment: Your problem is similar to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24389. Try solution discussed there.